# Broken packages problem trying to install python-dev

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, dependencies

I need to install python-dev in order to install another application, but when I do `sudo apt-get install python-dev` I get: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:` with a list of dependencies. So I added them until there were no more dependencies, leaving the command line as: `sudo apt-get install python-dev libpython2.7-dev  python2.7-dev libexpat1-dev libexpat1`.

After this I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.1.0-6+b3) but 2.1.0-6+deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I opened Synaptic and searched for broken packages but there were none. I also tried to use aptitude instead of apt-get:

```
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev{ab} libpython-dev{a} libpython2.7-dev{a} python-dev
  python2.7-dev{a}
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/19.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 31.6 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.1.0-6+b3) but 2.1.0-6+deb8u1 is installed.

 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libexpat1-dev [Not Installed]                     
2)     libpython-dev [Not Installed]                     
3)     libpython2.7-dev [Not Installed]                   
4)     python-dev [Not Installed]                         
5)     python2.7-dev [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

So far so good (I thought), so I pressed 'Y', but it listed a lot of packages to remove and asked me to continue. Since I had doubts about this, I pressed 'n', but now when I do it all over again to copy the packages proposed for deletion, it does nothing:

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Right now I'm working with a Local Repository since I'm getting troubles to connect to the debian ftp (probably because of the network administrator or a proxy). So my sources.lst are:

```
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

##Local Repository
deb file:/media/ramon-debian/JimiHendrix/debian8repo/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb file:/media/ramon-debian/JimiHendrix/debian8repo/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Please post your `sources.lst`. Which version of Debian are you running?

Comment: I edited the question to post the sources.lst. I'm using debian 8.

Comment: I found this one very useful. Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/a/922325/498798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the repository you're using.
https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/expat shows that in Debian, there's no package `libexpat1_2.1.0-6+b3`...

Delete the apt cache using `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then `apt-get update` again. If your local mirror is OK, you should have a working (consistent) list of available packages. If not, then the local repo is broken...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried what you said, but it seems that my repo is broken as the matter of fact. I opened Synaptic and searched for python-dev and it says that the package is broken.

Comment: Don't forget `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! I downloaded the packages `libexpat1_2.1.0-7_amd64.deb` and `libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-7_amd64.deb` from the link [@Jan posted](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/expat) and installed them with `dpkg -i package.deb`.

Comment: I did that and also `sudo apt-get build-dep python-dev` then installed the python-dev after :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the `aptitude` tool - you'll see this suggestion a lot, but without instruction. I had a similar issue with a GNU Radio PyBOMBS build (on a Raspberry Pi 3b, FWIW) that no amount of changing mirrors, `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, or `apt-get clean` would fix.

Provided your mirror has the target package, the `aptitude` fix for me was to *deny* the first solution which, as you experienced, did nothing. Then, the second solution was a downgrade, which installed the needed dependency!

I would get:

```
libevent-dev : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (= 2.0.21-stable-2) but 2.0.21-stable-2+deb8u1 is to be installed
```

This was the solution for me (for libevent-dev, but should work for libexpat1-dev):

```
# aptitude install libevent-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5{a} libevent-dev{b} libevent-extra-2.0-5{a} libevent-openssl-2.0-5{a} 
  libevent-pthreads-2.0-5{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 506 kB of archives. After unpacking 1586 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libevent-dev : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (= 2.0.21-stable-2) but 2.0.21-stable-2+deb8u1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libevent-dev [Not Installed]                       

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:                                          
1)     libevent-2.0-5 [2.0.21-stable-2+deb8u1 (now) -> 2.0.21-stable-2 (stable)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libevent-2.0-5 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5{a} libevent-dev libevent-extra-2.0-5{a} libevent-openssl-2.0-5{a} 
  libevent-pthreads-2.0-5{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 641 kB of archives. After unpacking 1552 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
```

After that, I could resume the PyBOMBS build with met dependencies (well, after doing a similar fix for libboost-dev...).

Comment: Same issue here, but with a different package. After screwing around with editing files, clearing caches and whatever, all without any success, finally fixing it with aptitude was a real smooth experience. This should be the accepted solution.